# Multiple services using Firebase job dispatcher in android

Tags: firebase-job-dispatcher

For an android app, i want start three services using firebase job dispatcher on different days. Can I use same FirebaseDispatcher object for all the three jobs?. Meanwhile, How to maintain same FirebaseDispatcher object even though app is closed?. If i use static object it will be cleared if app crashes. So how to maintain my FirebaseDispatcher object for scheduling multiple services using same dispatcher object? or Can I create different FirebaseDispatcher object for different services? Is it good practice?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use the same FirebaseJobDispatcher for all Jobs.
2. When the application is closed, your Jobs will be executed. How? This is the Android OS concern.
3. You simply describe when and how your Jobs will be launched. It's all. Read the documentation again and **see the comments in the source code of the library**.
4. You can create the new FirebaseJobDispatcher for different Jobs.
5. Misapplication of static objects -- is bad practice.

So

```
FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher1 =
    new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(context));

Job job1 = dispatcher1.newJobBuilder()
    .setService(YourService1.class)
    .setTag(Const.JOB_TAG_1)
    // more options to run
    .build();

Job job2 = dispatcher1.newJobBuilder()
    .setService(YourService2.class)
    .setTag(Const.JOB_TAG_2)
    // ...
    .build();

dispatcher1.mustSchedule(job1);

FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher2 =
    new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(context));

dispatcher2.mustSchedule(job2);

dispatcher1.cancel(Const.JOB_TAG_1);
dispatcher2.cancel(Const.JOB_TAG_2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.